# Global minor mode not global?

Tags: minor-mode

I am trying to write a global minor mode.  The following illustrates my problem:

```
(define-minor-mode global-foo-mode :global t :lighter " FOO")
```

then run

```
M-x global-foo-mode
```

The message displayed is

```
Global-Foo mode disabled
```

The current buffer does *not* display the FOO lighter in its mode line, but every other buffer does.  Subsequent invocations of `M-x global-foo-mode` in various buffers seem to enable and disable the mode on the current buffer, but not globally as I would expect.  Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you are leaving out the required argument DOC when you call `define-minor-mode`. (Or more accurately, you are passing `:global` as the DOC parameter)

Either provide a doc string or nil as the second argument:

```
(define-minor-mode global-foo-mode nil :global t :lighter " FOO")
```

Note that `define-minor-mode` is a macro. You can see how it is expanded. Put point just after the closing paren and call `M-x pp-macroexpand-last-sexp`. Try this with and without the `nil` in there, and you'll see that in your case `:global` is being used where the docstring should be.